# Incremental training of a large language model

Tags: algorithm, large-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers, llama, mistral-7b

**Context:**

I have my data in multiple `.txt` files and my LLM (`Mistral-7B-v0.1`) needs to be trained on these files for text completion purpose.

**Use case:**

The issue on my side is that, I want to train the LLM in an incremental fashion because I don't have all my files right at the moment. I will have access some of them after sometime.

**What will I try?**

Consider that I start from a base model and its base tokenizer.

Now before I train my model on the first `.txt` file, I will train my tokenizer to cover the vocabulary from the first `.txt` file. Lets name it as `tokenizer-1` Now, using the new tokenizer, I trained my base model and saved it as `checkpoint-1`.

Now, before training the LLM on the second `.txt` file, I will again train the `tokenizer-1` to cover the vocabulary from the second `.txt` file. Lets name it as `tokenizer-2`. And now, I will train the `checkpoint-1` further on the second `.txt` file to get a new model. Lets name it as `checkpoint-2`.

**My Question:**

Since the `checkpoint-1` was trained using `tokenizer-1`, and since now I am training the `checkpoint-1` further on `tokenizer-2`, doesn't the model weights of `checkpoint-1` get irrelevant w.r.t `tokenizer-2`?

**PS:**

I am deliberately adding `llama` as keyword below to reach out the wider community and this question is applicable to any LLM in general.